Customize the appearance of the java awt FileDialog
Is there a way to customize the appearance of the FileDialog in the AWT library?
I understand that it is a native window, but are there any options for customization? Currently, I am using JFileChooser, which is easy to modify, but it lacks several native features such as drag and drop, multiselect with cursor dragging, and many others.
I would like to learn how to change fonts, font color, background, button colors, and more in FileDialog.

Adding Drag-and-Drop and so on to a JFileChooser seems unavoidable. Instead of Swing you could use JavaFX (OpenJFX).

Hello Vasiliy, you can see here.
